# I use github action and vercel to deploy my project(vite+react+pnpm) to vercel, action said error: "Error: spawn pnpm ENOENT"

Tags: github, action, vite, vercel, pnpm

when I push my github project, the github action was executed, but it failed, the error message from the action is below:

```
Run vercel build --prod --token=***
Vercel CLI 28.10.3
Detected `pnpm-lock.yaml` generated by pnpm 7...
Installing dependencies...
Error: spawn pnpm ENOENT
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

this is my action yml settings:

```
name: Vercel Deployment
env:
  VERCEL_ORG_ID: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_ORG_ID }}
  VERCEL_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_PROJECT_ID }}
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  Deploy-Production:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18.12.1
      - name: Install Vercel CLI
        run: npm install --global vercel@latest
      - name: Pull Vercel Environment Information
        run: vercel pull --yes --environment=production --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build Project Artifacts
        run: vercel build --prod --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
      - name: Deploy Project Artifacts to Vercel
        run: vercel deploy --prebuilt --prod --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you find a workaround for this @no13bus?

Comment: No, util now, I ask vercel for help, they said I can try "vercel delploy" in the local enveriment, it is ok. But when I use github action, it does not work. I do not know how to resolve it

Comment: Hello, I encountered the same issue myself in the monorepo. The problem for me was that on Vercel I had [Root Directory](https://vercel.com/finshape/alfons/settings) defined and I was using Vercel CLI with --cwd option like `vercel pull --yes --pwd projects/my-project`. So removing Root directory from Vercel solved the issue for me. You can play with `./vercel/projects.json` file yourself to see if it helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this same error too, but I fixed it by

- install [pnpm first](https://github.com/pnpm/action-setup)
- install the Vercel CLI via `pnpm add --global vercel@latest`:

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy-production:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 18
      - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
        name: Install pnpm
        id: pnpm-install
        with:
          version: 7
          run_install: false
      - name: Install Vercel CLI
        run: pnpm add --global vercel@latest
      - name: Pull Vercel Environment Information
        run: vercel pull --yes --environment=production --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build Project Artifacts
        run: vercel build --prod --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
      - name: Deploy Project Artifacts to Vercel
        run: vercel deploy --prebuilt --prod --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
```